# Second Broadcast receiver intent never getting captured in a Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, screen

I am trying to capture the following two broadcasts (android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON & android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF) from my running foreground service (code below).

Only "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" is getting captured. 
**if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"))** in onReceive() never gets fired ... neither does myBroadcast_screenoff.

What am I doing wrong here?

(Basic question is how to capture two different intents from a single service)

```
public class ServiceDataSaver extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


BroadcastReceiver myBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")) {
            Log.v("datasaver", "Screen just turned on");
        }

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF")) {
            Log.v("datasaver", "Screen just turned off");
        }
    }
};

BroadcastReceiver myBroadcast_screenoff = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF")) {
            Log.v("datasaver", "Screen just turned off");
        }
    }
};



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
    filter.setPriority(999);
    registerReceiver(myBroadcast, filter);


    IntentFilter filter_screenoff = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
    filter_screenoff.setPriority(999);
    registerReceiver(myBroadcast_screenoff, filter_screenoff);      
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Do not forget to unregister the receiver!!!
    //this.unregisterReceiver);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


    makeServiceForeground(intent);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;        
}

public void makeServiceForeground(Intent receivedIntent) {
    final int myID = 1234;

    // The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification
    Intent returningintent = new Intent(this, MainActivitySlidingLayer.class);
    receivedIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            returningintent, 0);

    // This constructor is deprecated. Use Notification.Builder instead
    Notification notice = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Facebook is Blocked", System.currentTimeMillis());

    // This method is deprecated. Use Notification.Builder instead.
    notice.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Facebook is blocked",
            "Click here to unblock it ...", pendIntent);

    notice.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(myID, notice);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just the typo. You're not registering for SCREEN_OFF intent.

In OnCreate()

```
  IntentFilter filter_screenoff = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
```

should be

```
  IntentFilter filter_screenoff = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
```

and of course you'd better use the constants provided by `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` anyway.

Comment: Yes, silly silly me. It was a copy paste error. I guess 4am is not the best time to do this, thanks for your time.